# Wrong US week number calculation for 1st jan using datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, week-number, datepart

SQL server [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function has two options to retrieve week number;
`ISO_WEEK` and `WEEK`. I Know the difference between the two, I want to have week numbers based on Sunday start standard as followed in the US; i.e. `WEEK`. But it doesn't handles partial weeks the way I expected. e.g.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2015-12-31')    --53
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-01')    --1
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-03')    --2
```

gives two different week numbers for a single week, divided in two years. I wanted to implement something like in the following link for week days.

[Week numbers according to US standard](https://savvytime.com/week-number/united-states/2016)

Basically I would like something like this;

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2015-12-31')    --1
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-01')    --1
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-03')    --2
```

**EDIT:**
Basically I am not good with the division of a single week into two, I have to perform some calculations based on week numbers and the fact that a single week to be divided isn't acceptable. So if above isn't possible.

Is it possible that the week number one would start from 2016-01-03. i.e. what I would in that case would be something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2015-12-31')    --53
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-01')    --53
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2016-01-03')    --1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the US numbering, you can do this by taking the WEEK number of the end of the week rather than the date itself.

First ensure that the setting for first day of the week is in fact Sunday on your system. You can verify this by running `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`; this should return 7 for Sunday. If it doesn't, run `SET DATEFIRST 7;` first.

```
SELECT 
    end_of_week=DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '20151231')), '20151231'),
    week_day=DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '20151231')), '20151231'));
```

Which will return 2016/01/02 - 1.

Comment: this basically returns:
2016-01-03 - 1

Comment: @SaifUllah Depends on what the first day of the week is on your system. Run `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`, for Sunday this should return 7. If it doesn't, run `SET DATEFIRST 7` first.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish generate week number of a date, it will return the week number of the year(input date)

Thus, I think sql server treat '2015-12-31' as the last week of 2015.

Comment: I agree, especially since it is thursday of the last week of the year. :-)

Comment: can you please elaborate what exactly do you mean there?

Comment: Your input date ('2015-12-31')'s year is 2015 but not 2016, thus, it will treated as the last week of 2015 as this date is not belong to 2016.